# Using an Angular factory for route resolves

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using UI-Router, but I'm not sure that it matters.

What I'm trying to do is extract away my current resolve logic into a factory/service, such that it doesn't pollute my `$stateProvider` definition. This is a short example:

Here's my current config: (`$kinvey` is a service that returns a promise)

```
.state('home', {
  url: '/',
  views: {
    'header': headerView,
    'content': {
      templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
    },
    'footer': footerView
  },
  resolve: {
    user: ['$kinvey', function ($kinvey) {
      return $kinvey.User.me();
    }]
  }
})
```

And what I'd like it to be:

```
  resolve: {
    'user': 'DataResolverService.userResolve'
  }
```

**DataResolverService**

```
.factory('DataResolverService', function DataResolverService($kinvey) {

  var userResolve = {
    user: ['$kinvey', function ($kinvey) {
      return $kinvey.User.me();
    }]
  };

  // public API
  return {
    userResolve: userResolve
  };

});
```

I seem to be getting a `Unknown provider: DataResolverService.userResolveProvider <- DataResolverService.userResolve`. Is this because factories/services can't be run like this inside the `config()` block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using a service in the config block. You should be able to inject it like this:

```
resolve: {
    'user': ['DataResolverService', function(DataResolverService){
        return DataResolverService.userResolve;
    }]
}
```

An alternative approach would be to hide the injection mess in a constant (don't forget to include `$injector` as a dependency):

```
resolve: $injector.get('ResolveMap')

app.constant('ResolveMap',{
    'user': ['DataResolverService', function(DataResolverService){
        return DataResolverService.userResolve;
     }]
});
```

There was a discussion around this here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/QtO8QoxSjYw

Comment: As a "best practice" note, is there a better way to do this? Seems kind of ugly - but the alternative is worse.

Comment: just added an alternative that hides the "ugly" in a constant